# Why is the along track resolution of the MRO's SHARAD limited to >300m?

Tags: geology, image-processing, mars-reconnaissance-orbiter, synthetic-aperture-radar, resolution

I've been reading about the SHAllow RADar instrument on the Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter,  but I am struggling to understand why the along track resolution of its radargrams is so large.

As I understand it, the along-track resolution of a focused SAR is given as $\frac{\lambda R_0}{2 L_s}$, where $L_s$ is the synthetic aperture length and $R_0$ is the platform altitude. This results in a theoretical maximum resolution of $\frac{l}{2}$, where $l$ is the antenna length. Other factors, such as windowing to reduce sidelobes and the aperture-illumination taper factor degrade the resolution slightly, but it should still be in the range of several meters.

I also know that SHARAD averages multiple samples to reduce speckle and increase SNR, and that the PRF of ~700Hz constrains the along-track resolution to $\geq\frac{2V}{PRF}$ (V is spacecraft velocity), but this also gives an along track resolution of several meters.

However, several sources (for example, [NASA's Page on the MRO](https://mars.nasa.gov/mro/mission/instruments/sharad/)) give SHARAD's horizontal resolution as between 300 and 3000m. Why is it so coarse? What am I missing? The few sources I can find describing actual SHARAD measurements give very short synthetic aperture lengths (on the order of 6000m) and [this presentation](https://pds-geosciences.wustl.edu/workshops/SHARAD_MARSIS_Mar14/Campbell_SHARAD-PROCESSING.pdf) describes a tradeoff between SNR and synthetic aperture length and includes a diagram showing an 8-9 second integration time and a corresponding 75m resolution.

Does this imply that SHARAD data could be processed to acquire much finer resolution, but that the resulting radargrams would be very noisy? If SHARAD had had a much higher PRF so that it could still average multiple looks at each along-track cell (assuming it was still low enough to avoid range ambiguities), would it have been able to achieve higher resolutions with the same amount of noise?

Thank you!